# Avoid crashing from shared drive

Tags: .net, crash, save, shared, drive

my program is located on a shared drive, but it can happen that the computer loses the connection to the shared drive, for whatever reason. the program would crash. is there a way to create a "cache" or something so that the program can still be used? i heard that there is a compiler setting in Delphi, but i found nothing about .net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\VC\bin\editbin.exe" /swaprun:CD /swaprun:NET YourApp.exe
```